# C matrix of strings

Tags: c

I have a problem which says:

> Given a matrix of size n x m with type of date strings of
>   characters.
>  Make a program who print the string of maximum lenght
>   from every line of matrix.

I have made something, but when I try to execute it doesn't work.
I don't know why. Can someone give me some advice?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char tab[50][255];
    int m, n, i, j;
    printf("\n Dati numarul de linii : ");
    scanf("%d", &m);
    printf("\n Dati numarul de coloane : ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for(i=0; i<m; i++)
    {
       for(j=0; j<n; j++)
       {
          printf("\n Elementul [%d][%d] de tip sir de caractere : ", i+1, j+1);
          scanf("%s", tab[50][255]);
       }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is your input and expected output?

Answer (score 1):

```
char tab[50][5][255];
int m, n, i, j;
printf("\n Dati numarul de linii : ");
scanf("%d", &m);
printf("\n Dati numarul de coloane : ");
scanf("%d", &n);
for(i=0; i<m; i++)
{
   for(j=0; j<n; j++)
   {
      printf("\n Elementul [%d][%d] de tip sir de caractere : ", i+1, j+1);
      scanf("%s", tab[i][j]);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your

```
scanf("%s", tab[50][255]);
```

statement.
If you wanna input strings the use `fgets` as follows

```
for(i=0; i<m; i++)
{
      printf("\n Elementul [%d][%d] de tip sir de caractere : ", i+1, j+1);
      fgets(tab[i], 225, stdin);
}
```

To print the string of maximum length use `strlen` function to get the string length and do some comparison to find it.